# why this expression produce error?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm working with vb.net and entity framework.

In my form , I have 2 comboboxes : Article and price. ( For both comboboxes , .Selectedvalue is an integer )

If I use this expression :

```
 Dim gj As IEnumerable(Of Myobject)
 gj = (From t In context.myobjects Where t.art=Article.SelectedValue And t.prc=price.SelectedValue Select t).ToList
```

an error is produced :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dllAdditional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

If I use this code :

```
Dim a as integer=Article.SelectedValue

Dim c as integer= price.selectedvalue

Dim gj As IEnumerable(Of Myobject)

gj = (From t In context.myobjects Where t.art = a And t.prc = c
   Select t).ToList
```

everything is OK.

What I have wrong in first expression , and how should I modify to make it work , because I don't want to use extra variables like in the second code.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The compile-time type of `Article.SelectedValue` is `Object`, and VB inserts a call to `CompareObjectEqual()` to mimic VB comparison rules at runtime.
Unfortunately, EF doesn't recognize that call.

Casting `SelectedValue` to `Integer` might work, unless EF fails to recognize the cast either.

You probably have no better solution than the temporary variables.

Comment: Ok , but why the code work without problems if the .selectedvalue of the comboboxes are string ?

for example this expression work without problems :

Dim gj As IEnumerable(Of Myobject)
 gj = (From t In context.myobjects Where t.name=MyName.Selectedvalue
        Select t).ToList

Comment: @alex: I don't know why that would work.  Try inspecting the expression trees in the debugger.

Comment: It's strange , but now I modified my code calling the ToString and now everything works :  gj = (From t In context.myobjects Where t.art=Article.SelectedValue.ToString And t.prc=price.SelectedValue.Tostring Select t).ToList. This expression works without problems, but I want to know is this correct and can this produce a correct result everytime ?

Comment: Please , any suggestion about my last comment ? Thank you !

Comment: @alex: I would guess that EF only knows how to handle a comparison between the same types.

Comment: So you think is a risk to keep a such comparison method  , or is there a possibility that EF try to make a conversion and if something goes wrong display an error ?